# Missing PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder from GooglePlayeServices.Places version 60

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm programming an android app with visual studio in c#.
I'm using Places for the autocomplete features.
i just updated the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices NuGet to the last current version 60.1142.0 and now

```
var intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.ModeFullscreen)
                    .SetFilter(autocompleteFilter)
                    .Build(this);
```

does not compile anymore:

IntentBuilder "Error CS0426: The type name 'IntentBuilder' does not exist in the type 'PlaceAutocomplete'"

I can understand that the api is changed, but how. even the documentation refer to this old piece of code.

TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Place` **v60.1142.0** package/nuget is broken.

The Java classes bundled within the package are correct and do have the `PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder` class:

```
com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceAutocomplete$IntentBuilder.class
```

But the C# bindings are not exposing it, a `Metadata.xml` transform is missing:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui']/class[@name='PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder']" name="extends">java.lang.Object</attr>
```

Re: [GooglePlayServicesComponents places Transforms Metadata.xml](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/blob/master/places/source/Transforms/Metadata.xml)

I built from source last week to fix it for someone and have not even looked at [bugzilla.xamarin.com](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) to see if it had been reported.

Comment: Bugzilla link: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61099
GitHub Issue Link: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/82

Comment: Had the same issue. it best to report the bug